# Good design pattern to collect data in a complex object

Tags: java, design-patterns

Let's say, I have a complex object hierarchy, something like:

```
public class ClassRoom
{
    private ClassRoomInfo classRoomInfo;
    private List<Student> students;
    ...
}
```

I get this object as an input from client, but the object might not be filled completely. For example, client can provide very minimal details like `studentId(s)` or minor information in the `classRoomInfo` object. I want to write a `DataCollector` class for this object, which would collect all the missing data upfront.

What would be the best design pattern in this case?

Comment: "collect all the missing data.." from where?

Comment: I have external services and databases from where I can get the data.

Comment: Try Builder patter. Its used for building complex objects

Comment: Using the same object both as a container to transfer data from the client and as a business object that needs to be hydrated from a database seems like a bad idea.

Comment: What do you envisage the `DataCollector` looking like?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to *Lazy Load* data when needed.The getters for the members of `ClassRoom` class should suffice for this purpose.

A separate `DataCollector` class is not recommended as it will force you to expose setters in `ClassRoom` for all members.

This [link](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html) (and Book) should tell you more about Lazy load  .

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach. The idea is to treat the `ClassRoom` as an instance of the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), where every object in the hierarchy knows how to "fill itself in" using a `DataCollector`. If an object is already filled in, it responds to being asked to fill itself in by returning itself; if it is not filled in, it gets the necessary information from the `DataCollector` and builds a new instance of its own class which is filled in (the objects themselves are therefore immutable - you might prefer to have the objects mutate themselves, but i usually lean towards using immutable objects to represent data).

I've defined an interface `Fillable` for objects which know how to fill themselves in. However, this isn't really necessary, as the `fillIn` method is never invoked polymorphically. It's just documentation, really.

I've assumed that the filling-in process is pretty simple. Obviously, it could be more complex, both in detecting what is filled in (eg an empty list of students might indicate that the list has not been populated), and in how it goes about filling it in. If you applied this design to your real problem, you will find that the `DataCollector` becomes incredibly complicated. You will need to factor it differently; you might want to move more of the collection logic into the domain classes, or to split it into per-class DAOs (`ClassRoomInfoDataCollector` etc).

```
public interface Fillable<T> {
    public T fillIn(DataCollector collector);
}

public class ClassRoom implements Fillable<ClassRoom> {
    private final ClassRoomInfo classRoomInfo;
    private final List<Student> students;

    private ClassRoom(ClassRoomInfo classRoomInfo, List<Student> students) {
        this.classRoomInfo = classRoomInfo;
        this.students = students;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassRoom fillIn(DataCollector collector) {
        ClassRoomInfo filledInClassRoomInfo = classRoomInfo.fillIn(collector);
        List<Student> filledInStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();
        for (Student student : students) {
            filledInStudents.add(student.fillIn(collector));
        }
        if (filledInClassRoomInfo == classRoomInfo && filledInStudents.equals(students)) return this;
        return new ClassRoom(filledInClassRoomInfo, filledInStudents);
    }
}

public class ClassRoomInfo implements Fillable<ClassRoomInfo> {
    final String roomNumber;
    final Integer capacity;

    private ClassRoomInfo(String roomNumber, int capacity) {
        this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassRoomInfo fillIn(DataCollector collector) {
        if (capacity != null) return this;
        return new ClassRoomInfo(roomNumber, collector.getClassRoomCapacity(roomNumber));
    }
}

public class Student implements Fillable<Student> {
    final int id;
    final String name;

    private Student(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Student fillIn(DataCollector collector) {
        if (name != null) return this;
        return new Student(id, collector.getNameOfStudent(id));
    }
}

public class DataCollector {
    public String getNameOfStudent(int id) {
        ...
    }

    public int getClassRoomCapacity(String roomNumber) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is good! but I have a doubt. Is it good to expose fillIn() methods in the data objects? I think objects should be independent of such kind of methods.

Comment: I think that's part of the domain logic, and as such, belongs in the domain objects. You could separate it out into other objects, but then you run the risk of having an [anaemic domain model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). I could be persuaded that it's not part of the domain logic, but at the moment, this seems like the simplest thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Facade Design Pattern". Hope it can help you. you can find a good description on Facade in http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/facade-design-pattern/

Comment: what do you consider the subsystem which is difficult to use in this case?

Comment: As per my understanding you can think of a ClassRoom object as your key. All other implicit object like Student or ClassRoomInfo as one one subsystem. when the client request for ClassRoom details, it send instruction to multiple subsystems present inside the classRoom and executes a sequence of operation and completes the objective. Please let me know if i am wrong.